# RoR(wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 4) Mobylette Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails -v 4.2.10. I am getting the following error, when executing rails s. I am using Passenger standalone to deploy the app.

> ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 5, expected 4)):
>   mobylette (3.5) >lib/mobylette/resolvers/chained_fallback_resolver.rb:43:in
>   find_templates'

chained_fallback_resolver.rb

```
module Mobylette
  module Resolvers
    class ChainedFallbackResolver < ::ActionView::FileSystemResolver
      DEFAULT_PATTERN = "{:path}/:prefix/:action{.:locale,}
{.:formats,}{.:handlers,}"

      # Initializes the fallback resolver with a default
      # mobile format.
      #
      def initialize(formats = {}, view_paths = ['app/views'])
        @fallback_formats = formats
        @paths = view_paths.map { |view_path| 
File.expand_path(view_path)}
        super(@paths.first, DEFAULT_PATTERN)
      end

      # Updates the fallback resolver replacing the
      # fallback format hash.
      #
      # formats - hash of fallbacks, example:
      #
      #   formats = {
      #     mobile: [:mobile, :html],
      #     iphone: [:iphone, :ios, :mobile, :html],
      #     android: [:android, :mobile],
      #     ...
      #   }
      #
      # It will add the fallback chain array of the 
      # request.format to the resolver.
      # 
      # If the format.request is not defined in formats,
      # it will behave as a normal FileSystemResovler.
      #
      def replace_fallback_formats_chain(formats)
        @fallback_formats = formats
      end

      private

      # Private: finds the right template on the filesystem,
      #         using fallback if needed
      #
      **def find_templates(name, prefix, partial, details)
       # checks if the format has a fallback chain
        if @fallback_formats.has_key?(details[:formats].first)
          details = details.dup
          details[:formats] = 
Array.wrap(@fallback_formats[details[:formats].first]) 
        end**
        super(name, prefix, partial, details)
      end

      # Helper for building query glob string based on resolver's 
      #  pattern.
      def build_query(path, details)
       query = @pattern.dup

       prefix = path.prefix.empty? ? "" : "#
{escape_entry(path.prefix)}\\1"
        query.gsub!(/\:prefix(\/)?/, prefix)

        partial = escape_entry(path.partial? ? "_#{path.name}" : 
path.name)
        query.gsub!(/\:action/, partial)

       details.each do |ext, variants|
          query.gsub!(/\:#{ext}/, "{#
{variants.compact.uniq.join(',')}}")
        end

        query.gsub!(/\:path/, "#{@paths.compact.uniq.join(',')}")
      end
    end
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gem 'mobylette', git: 'https://github.com/jonigual/mobylette.git' fixed the issue. 
[Github](https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette/issues/49)